# Convert data as string into a number

Tags: excel, type-conversion, vba

I have a trouble with converting a date as String into Long. Generally speaking, I don't know how to convert dates into numbers using VBA. There is an overflow in the line marked with 'OVERFLOW. Why?
PS: The first value of the array "daty" is "2018-03-26".

```
Sub Sortuj_daty()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

Dim i As Long
Dim daty(1 To 10) As String
Dim daty_int(1 To 10) As Long
Dim daty_uporzadkowane(1 To 10) As String

    For i = 1 To 10
        daty(i) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        daty_int(i) = CInt(CDate(Format(daty(i), "yyyy-mm-dd"))) 'OVERFLOW
    Next i

    For j = 1 To 10
        daty_uporzadkowane(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(daty_int, j)
        ws.Cells(j, 2) = daty_uporzadkowane(j)
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest to split the OVERFLOW-LINE into at least 3 lines of code. Thus, you can see were the error occures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/integer-data-type) you will see value ranges for Integer.

Today's date casted as int is 43180 which exeeds integer.

Use `Long` ( `CLng()` ) instead